# O que realmente significa "from modulox import *"

Tags: python, tkinter, import

Até onde eu sei isso importa todas as classes e funções de um certo arquivo sem precisar referenciá-lo no código, certo? Porém estou começando achar que `from modulo import *` não significa isso.

Eu estava estudando a biblioteca tkinter e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser
```

Se no primeiro `import` já usou o `*`, por que precisaria importar o `colorchooser` de novo? Na verdade aparentemente o `colorchooser` nem foi importado.

Se eu tentar usar o `colorchooser` sem usar a segunda linha ele simplesmente diz que não está definido. Por que precisa importar duas vezes o `colorchooser`?

Answer (score 6):

Você não importa duas vezes. O uso do asterisco não significa necessariamente que você irá importar todas as classes, funções ou variáveis disponíveis dentro de um módulo. Aí temos dois casos...

1. Não foi definida a variável `__all__` em arquivo **__init__.py**, daí o Python carregará tudo o que estiver definido lá dentro (o que não pode ser o melhor dos comportamentos), ou
2. Importar tudo aquilo que é considerado necessário e que foi definido dentro de `__all__`, o que te dá muito mais controle sobre o que está sendo carregado.

Por exemplo você tem um módulo chamado **modulo** e no diretório dele há dois arquivos, um contendo as classes, o **somas.py**:

```py
class Media:
    ...

class Soma:
    ...
```

E o outro o **__init__.py** que, inclusive, assinala que este diretório é um módulo:

```py
__all__ = ("Media",)

from .somas import Media, Soma
```

Neste cenário se você fizer:

```
>>> from modulo import *
>>> a = Media()
>>> b = Soma()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Soma' is not defined
```

Você não consegue usar a classe `Soma` pois apenas `Media` foi carregada automaticamente.

Sendo necessário fazer a carga dela manualmente (neste caso somente da classe `Soma`):

```
>>> from teste import Soma
>>> b = Soma()
```

Ou, dependendo do caso, acrescentando-a dentro de `__all__`.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito, então quando se faz um import de uma biblioteca, ao usar o *, ele importa tudo que estiver no arquivo __init__.py dessa pasta? então o tkinter não seria um arquivo "tkinter.py" mas uma pasta?

Comment: O asterisco no caso que estamos falando, vai importar o `__init__.py` do pacote (pasta) `tkinter` **se ele existir**. Mas o asterisco por si só, importa os dados apenas do módulo especificado, como eu disse na minha resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440593/157404

Answer (score 5):

Utilizar o asterisco (`*`) irá sim importar todos os dados (variáveis, funções e classes) do módulo que você especificou no `from`, não tendo outra finalidade.

O que acontece, é que ao fazer `from tkinter import *`, você está importando do pacote [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) o arquivo `__init__.py`. E diferentemente do que você pensa, o [`colorchooser`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.colorchooser.html) não está dentro do arquivo que você importa, pois ele é um outro módulo dentro do pacote.

Logo, se você apenas realizar a primeira importação, você não poderá acessar o *colorchooser* e consequentemente será gerado um `NameError`.

```
from tkinter import *             # Aqui você importa tudo do __init__.py
from tkinter import colorchooser  # Aqui você importa o módulo colorchooser.py do pacote
```

Você pode comprovar que o *colorchooser* é um módulo utilizando a função `help`.

```
>>> help(colorchooser)
Help on module tkinter.colorchooser in tkinter:

NAME
    tkinter.colorchooser
...
```

---

Veja [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules) o conteúdo do pacote. Você também pode ver o conteúdo indo para o diretório `<python_path>/lib/tkinter` ou executando `help(tkinter)` para olhar a documentação.

Comment: Neste caso, se o __init__.py n existisse. ele importaria tudo da pasta tkinter?

Comment: Não, apenas importaria o pacote com suas informações. Você mesmo pode fazer esse teste criando seu próprio pacote e colocando ou não o arquivo `__init__` para ver no que resulta.

Comment: So mais uma duvida, se tiver um pacote e dentro desse pacote tiver uma pasta. Ao importar ele usando asteristo essa pasta seria importada tbm?

Comment: Não. Vamos dizer que há a pasta `modulo2` dentro de `modulo1`. Nesse caso a importação para obter **somente** os dados do `modulo2` seria `from modulo1.modulo2 import *`. A não ser é claro que você já fizesse um importação com o `__all__` dentro do `modulo1`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, aparentemente tenho muita coisa ainda a aprender haha

Comment: Seria legala crescentar na resposta que a recomendação é __nunca__ usar `from x import *`: isso dificulta a manutençao (você não sabe de onde uma variável u função se originou), e atrapalalha inclusive as funcionalidades de auto-complete das IDEs - além de ter uma chance grande de conflito de nomes.
O ideal é ou importar todos os nomes explicitamente, ou importar o módulo, possivelmente com um nome encurtado - e usar sempre o prefixo. Por exemplo: `import tkinter as tk; button=tk.Button(...)`